# Как ASP.NET MVC определяет модель пришедшую через Post?

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net, post, mvc

Взято из учебного пособия.
Есть такой класс:

```
    public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public Student()
    {
        Courses = new List<Course>();
    }
}
```

Есть такая форма:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<fieldset>
    <legend>Студент</legend>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

    <div class="editor-label"><b>Имя</b></div>
    <div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)</div>

    <div class="editor-label"><b>Фамилия</b></div>
    <div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname)</div>

    <div class="editor-label"><b>Курсы</b></div>
    @foreach(Course c in ViewBag.Courses)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedCourses" value="@c.Id" 
               @(Model.Courses.Contains(c) ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "") />@c.Name <br />
    }

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Сохранить" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

И есть такой метод контроллера для post-запроса:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Student student, int[] selectedCourses)
```

Вопрос: Почему выбранные курсы пришли как отдельный аргумент, если по-моим понятиям список курсов входит в класс Студента?
Или даже если считать список выбранных курсов int-вскими значениями, а не классами Course, то почему класс Student воспринимается правильно, если ему не достает атрибута Courses?

Comment: Когда вы отправляете пост запрос, с этим запросом вы отправляете пост параметры (поглядите в инструментах разработчика в браузере), ASP.NET смотрит на параметры пост запроса, смотрит на параметры метода контроллера, и пытается их замапить.

Answer (score 5):

Потому что `name="selectedCourses"`.

Сделайте `name="student.selectedCourses"` и посмотрите, что получится.

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public List<int> selectedCourses { get; set; }

    public Student()
    {
        Courses = new List<Course>();
        selectedCourses = new List<int>();
    }
}
```